# setting max-size property doesn't work while code spliting with webpack

Tags: webpack, code-splitting

while playing with webpack, I found strange results with code spliting.

I'm trying to split modules to chunks with size range of (20kb ~ 0)

my configuration looks like below.

```
splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      maxSize: 20000,
      minSize: 0,
      name(module, chunks, cacheGroupKey) {
        const moduleFileName = module
          .identifier()
          .split('/')
          .reduceRight((item) => item);
        const allChunksNames = chunks.map((item) => item.name).join('~');
        return `${cacheGroupKey}/${allChunksNames}-${moduleFileName}`;
      }
    }
```

but when I analyze bundle generated, its odd.

[image]

and inspecting build result,
dir name 'defaultVender' automatically generated.

I thought this was some kind of 'splitWebpackPlugin' default setting, but seems not

it says default setting looks like below for webpack

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async',
      minSize: 20000,
      minRemainingSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

and above code definitly doesn't seems to generate 'defaultVender'..

any idea about this phenomenon?